# Where condition a outer applied sql query

Tags: sql-server

I am using a sql query but sorry to say unable to use a where condition. I post my query below.

```
SELECT * , CAST( RIGHT(FileNo,3) AS numeric) as IntFileNo 
FROM ExportLcs A
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT SUM(ReceivedTTUsd) AS TtTotal,
        SUM(ReceivedPDCUsd) AS PdcTotal,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ReceivedPDCUsd > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PdcCashCount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ReceivedPDCUsd > 0 THEN ConvertRate ELSE 0 END) AS PdcRateTotal,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ConvertRate > 0 THEN CEILING(ReceivedPDCUsd / ConvertRate) ELSE 0 END) AS PdcTotalUsd,
        Count(ExportLcId) AS TotalPaymentCount
        FROM dbo.ExportPayments G
        WHERE A.ExportLcId = G.ExportLcId AND (G.PdcTotal+G.PdcTotalUsd)>0
    ) AS G
```

I want to use condition like 
A.ExportLcId = G.ExportLcId AND (G.PdcTotal+G.PdcTotalUsd)>0
but and part not working.
Any one can help.

Comment: I don't think you are allowed to use column aliases in where, try to make it like this:
`having (SUM(ReceivedPDCUsd) + SUM(CASE WHEN ConvertRate > 0 THEN CEILING(ReceivedPDCUsd / ConvertRate) ELSE 0 END)) > 0`

By the way, why don't you use outer join?

Answer (score 0):

How about having clause instead of where?

```
SELECT * , CAST(RIGHT(FileNo, 3) AS NUMERIC) AS IntFileNo
FROM dbo.ExportLcs AS A
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT SUM(ReceivedTTUsd) AS TtTotal
        , SUM(ReceivedPDCUsd) AS PdcTotal
        , SUM(CASE WHEN ReceivedPDCUsd > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PdcCashCount
        , SUM(CASE WHEN ReceivedPDCUsd > 0 THEN ConvertRate ELSE 0 END) AS PdcRateTotal
        , SUM(CASE WHEN ConvertRate > 0 THEN CEILING(ReceivedPDCUsd / ConvertRate) ELSE 0 END) AS PdcTotalUsd
        , COUNT(ExportLcId) AS TotalPaymentCount
    FROM dbo.ExportPayments AS G
    WHERE A.ExportLcId = G.ExportLcId
    HAVING (SUM(ReceivedPDCUsd) + SUM(CASE WHEN ConvertRate > 0 THEN CEILING(ReceivedPDCUsd / ConvertRate) ELSE 0 END)) > 0
) AS G;
```

Comment: @SanjoyDebnath mind telling what error does it output? _Not working_ is quite vague.

Comment: No error but query result not ok. Condition not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using Outer Join instead, so try the following:

```
SELECT * , CAST( RIGHT(FileNo,3) AS numeric) as IntFileNo from ExportLcs A left outer join
(
SELECT SUM(ReceivedTTUsd) AS TtTotal,
    SUM(ReceivedPDCUsd) AS PdcTotal,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ReceivedPDCUsd > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PdcCashCount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ReceivedPDCUsd > 0 THEN ConvertRate ELSE 0 END) AS PdcRateTotal,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ConvertRate > 0 THEN CEILING(ReceivedPDCUsd / ConvertRate) ELSE 0 END) AS PdcTotalUsd,
    Count(ExportLcId) AS TotalPaymentCount
    FROM dbo.ExportPayments) G
    on A.ExportLcId = G.ExportLcId where (G.PdcTotal+G.PdcTotalUsd)>0
```

Comment: In this case Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Invalid column name 'ExportLcId'.

Comment: @SanjoyDebnath, you should take care of the column names as i 
recreated the query using column names you provided.

Answer (score 0):

just put your part where clause outside.

```
SELECT * , CAST( RIGHT(FileNo,3) AS numeric) as IntFileNo 
FROM Export
    where   (G.PdcTotal+G.PdcTotalUsd)>0Lcs A
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT SUM(ReceivedTTUsd) AS TtTotal,
        SUM(ReceivedPDCUsd) AS PdcTotal,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ReceivedPDCUsd > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PdcCashCount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ReceivedPDCUsd > 0 THEN ConvertRate ELSE 0 END) AS PdcRateTotal,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ConvertRate > 0 THEN CEILING(ReceivedPDCUsd / ConvertRate) ELSE 0 END) AS PdcTotalUsd,
        Count(ExportLcId) AS TotalPaymentCount
        FROM dbo.ExportPayments G
        WHERE A.ExportLcId = G.ExportLcId
    ) AS G
```